# Showing $\frac{w}2 \sum_{i=0}^k(1+\alpha)^i=w\cdot\frac{2\alpha + 1}{2\alpha}$, for $0<\alpha<1$ and $k=\log_{1+\alpha}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify the value of $S$ from the summation to the one on the last line?

$$ \begin{align*}
S &= \frac{w}2 \left((1+\alpha)^0 + (1+\alpha)^1 + (1+\alpha)^2 + \ldots + (1+\alpha)^{k-1} + (1+\alpha)^k\right) \\
 &= \frac{w}2 \sum_{i=0}^k(1+\alpha)^i \\
 &= w\cdot\frac{2\alpha + 1}{2\alpha}
\end{align*} $$

given that $$0 < \alpha < 1$$ and $$k=\log_{1+\alpha}2$$ and $$w \text{ is an integer}$$

The equation is from my homework solutions, with no further explanations given. I don't think $w$ being an integer matters

Comment: It’s a geometric sum. Did you try applying the formula for that?

Comment: Btw this only works for special values of $\alpha$, since we need $k$ to be an integer.

Comment: Okay now plug in the definition of $k$ and simplify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the geometric formula as suggested in comments by [Milten](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/620957/milten) gives

$$ \begin{align*}
S &= \frac{w}2 \frac{1-(1+\alpha)^{(k+1)}}{1-(1+\alpha)} \\
 &= \frac{w}2 \frac{1-(1+\alpha)^{(k+1)}}{-\alpha} \\
 &= w \frac{1-2 (1+\alpha)}{-2\alpha} \\
 &= w \frac{-1 - 2\alpha}{-2\alpha} \\
 &= w \frac{1 + 2\alpha}{2\alpha}
\end{align*} $$

In step 3, using $k = log_{1+\alpha}2$